# AWS Log insights: specify @timestamp field output format/timezone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

When I use `fields @timestamp` in a Cloudwatch "log insights" query, it adds a column to the result table that is formatted into my local timezone like `2020-07-01T05:52:15.840+10:00`.

I don't want it to do the local timezone conversion, I want the column to display in UTC timezone.

How do I tell "log insights" to display the date in UTC timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@timestamp` output column timezone appears to be controlled by the timezone setting in the date range selector in the upper-right of the page - so you can get the timestamp to display in `UTC` by changing that, just remember you must now specify any absolute range in `UTC` timezone.  And you only get to choose between `UTC` and local timezone.

I will accept any alternate answer that gives a better way (I assumed there'd be some kind of formatting specifier I could add to the query, but I couldn't find anything in the doco).

Comment: Range component = date range selector in upper-right of screen.